# How do I change the user associated with a datastore record in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a user who changed the email address associated with his Google account.  He is no longer associated with datastore records that used to be associated with his User object.

Can I just update the user property on the datastore objects with his new email address?  Do I need to construct an actual User object to query or update these records, and if so, should I be using email, nickname, or user_id?

I am using Python if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snippet of the solution that ended up working for me:

```
    old_user = users.User(email="old@yahoo.com");
    new_user = users.User(email="new@gmail.com");
    changed = []

    things = model.Ball.all().filter("user =", old_user).fetch(500);
    for thing in things:
        thing.user = new_user
        changed += [thing]

    if len(changed) >= 500:
        db.put(changed)
        return

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: If the email address is associated with a Google account, user_id returns the unique permanent ID of the user, a str. This ID is always the same for the user regardless of whether the user changes her email address.

Comment: This doesn't address my question.  The User object returned for the user is different than it used to be - how do I pull the records associated with the old user object, and get them associated with the new one?

Comment: Different? Has the user another Google account?